# ASP.net Core (Deployment to IIS) error: An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type

Tags: asp.net-core

I am getting the following error
An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type

I am very very new to ASP.net in general and I am using entity framework..Can anyone help?

```
 public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/Users/Create");
            }


            
            var userexists = _context.User.Where(a => a.Username == User.Username && a.Password == User.Password);


            

            if (userexists.Count() > 0)
            {
                Response.Cookies.Append("userid", userexists.First().ID.ToString());

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }else
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./Index");
            }
            
        }
```

I believe the error is due to the .Where() but I am not sure.
Please help!

Comment: Hi, did you get this error when work in local?

Comment: 1. Open your **Exception Settings** window in Visual Studio and check the box for **Common Language Runtime Exceptions**. 2. Debug 3. Exception will pop up and you can get the exact stack trace/line.